# Is it possible to convert my appspot subdomain to a gmail id?

Tags: google-account

Need advice from a Google apps expert here. A few months ago, I tried desperately to register a gmail account that belongs to my name (`prahladyeri@gmail.com`), but the system absolutely refused saying that the email is already registered. I don't remember registering this gmail-id myself and nor does it exist anywhere.

Of late, however, I've realized that why the name is not available. That's because I use Google Appengine and I've registered the appspot subdomain `prahladyeri.appspot.com`. And, I've come to know recently that when we create an appspot subdomain, Google automatically blocks the subdomain name and prevents it to be used it as a gmail address.

Now, I would like to know how can I un-register the appspot subdomain `prahladyeri.appspot.com`, so the name becomes available as a proper email address to register? Is it even possible or the subdomain will just get recycled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short answer

As far as I understand, it's not possible.

## Reference

From [Uploading your application - App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/uploading)

> Accept the generated project ID or supply your own ID. This project ID
> is used as the App Engine application ID. Note that this ID can only
> be used once: if you subsequently delete your project, you won't be
> able to re-use the ID in a new project.